# Как Python работает с HTTP-сервером?

Tags: python, http

Как Python работает с HTTP-сервером?

Comment: по http-протоколу (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0), как и другие языки. берёте-выбираете фреймворк и вперёд.

Comment: Детали зависят от конкретной используемой для этого библиотеки. Питон - это библиотеки. Библиотек для работы с `HTTP` запросами у Питона много разных. Вас что именно интересует?

Comment: ;) ничто не мешает драфту стать без утверждения стандартом "де факто", не так ли? да знаю всё это. еще cern httpd помню

Comment: по третьему http https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/http3 ну, сервера, сами найдёте. по двойке тоже самое. привыкли мы к 1.1 ;)

Comment: еще про поддержку браузерами http3 https://caniuse.com/http3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от того что вы именно подразумеваете под словами `Как Python работает с HTTP-сервером?`

Если вам нужен HTTP сервер, то есть 2 удобных фреймворка.

- Django - для больших проектов, с полной поддержкой из коробки.
- Flask - для небольших проектов, я его часто предпочитаю для небольших сайтов.

Если вам нужен HTTP клиент, то лучше чем **requests** вы нечего не найдете

- requests - Там есть всё
- urllib.request - Маленькая фигня для простеньких запросов.

--- Добавлено спустя ---

В комментариях поправили. Есть ещё `aiohttp` там есть сервер и клиент, он тоже весьма неплох в удобстве использования.

Comment: евгений. пожалуйста, добавьте selenium, playwright, а то потом будут в непонятках "как так динамический html?"

Comment: для http-сервер еще выбирают aiohttp, fastapi много там чего еще

Comment: Ну selenium это всё-же драйвер управления браузером. Это совсем не те дебри. Да, aiohttp забыл, он действительно хорош.

Comment: Да вообще непонятно, что имел в виду автор вопроса. Мы читаем `HTTP` или раздаём.